# Pop from one list and append to the other

Tags: python

I want to create three small lists (holding three elements each) and one big list holding all three lists. 
Then I want to pop the last element from my first list and append it to the second list, and put it as the last element.

right now, the result looks like this after appending:

["banana", "apple"][" ", " ", " ", "lemon"][" "," "," "]

I want the result to look like this:

[" ", "banana", "apple"][" ", " ", "lemon"][" "," "," "]

```
class foodchain:
    temp1 = " "
    temp2 = " "
    temp3 = " "
    first = []
    second = []
    last = []
    biglist = []

    def __init__(self, temp1 = " ", temp2 = " ", temp3 = " "):
        self.temp1 = temp1
        self.temp2 = temp2
        self.temp3 = temp3
        self.first = ["banana", "apple", "lemon"]
        self.second = [self.temp1, self.temp2, self.temp3]
        self.last = [self.temp1, self.temp2, self.temp3]
        self.biglist = [self.first,self.second,self.last]

food = foodchain()

print(food.biglist)

food.biglist[1].append(food.biglist[0].pop())

print(food.biglist)
```

Comment: Are you sure that code produces that result? For me, it produces `AttributeError`. Please run that code you've posted, and copy-paste (never retype) the code into your question

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem but if you use list (mutable) in an instance variable, all the instances will share that variable. So the next foodchain you create will have the first, second, biglist etc same lists. And btw, since you want to pop items I recommend you use deque instead of lists. (Well, not if you recreate the variables in the `__init__` method, but then the instance variables are pointless)

Answer (score 2):

To concisely `pop` from one list and `push` to another:

```
> list0 = [1, 2, 3]
> list1 = [4, 5, 6]
> list1.append(list0.pop(-1))
> list0
[1, 2]
> list1
[4, 5, 6, 3]
```

The `pop()` has a parameter of `-1` to acquire the last element.

Comment: sorry, edited it.

right slightlynybbled, but I want it to allways show the empty space (" "), when the element has been removed

Comment: @orgee I think you want to use the '-1' as a parameter into `pop()`

Comment: tried that, result is still 
["banana", "apple"][" ", " ", " ", "lemon"][" "," "," "]
the result I want is 
[" ", "banana", "apple"][" ", " ", "lemon"][" "," "," "]

im new to this, don't know if I explained my problem really well!

Comment: That code does what you wanted in the question, other thing is that implicitly you also said "I want to pop the first element of the second list while doing this, and insert it at the begginig of the first list" in the example. So the thing you need to do is `from collections import deque` `deque1.appendleft(deque2.popleft())` `deque2.append(deque1.pop())`

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comments I propose this solution using deque from the lovely collections module

```
from collections import deque

class foodchain:
    def __init__(self, temp1=" ", temp2=" ", temp3=" "):
        self.temp1 = temp1
        self.temp2 = temp2
        self.temp3 = temp3
        self.first = deque(["banana", "apple", "lemon"])
        self.second = deque([self.temp1, self.temp2, self.temp3])
        self.last = deque([self.temp1, self.temp2, self.temp3])
        self.big_list = [self.first, self.second, self.last]
    def move21(self):
        self.first.appendleft(self.second.popleft())
        self.second.append(self.first.pop())
food = foodchain()
print(food.big_list)
food.move21()
print(food.big_list)

[deque(['banana', 'apple', 'lemon']), deque([' ', ' ', ' ']), deque([' ', ' ', ' '])]
[deque([' ', 'banana', 'apple']), deque([' ', ' ', 'lemon']), deque([' ', ' ', ' '])]
```